# How to reconfigure Emmet bindings in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm, emmet

I am using *WebStorm*, which comes pre-installed with *Emmet*. However, I cannot utilize any of the keyboard shortcuts, such as **Ctrl + /**, because I am using a Swedish keyboard layout.

My question is two-fold: Where do I find the keyboard shortcuts for *Emmet*, and how do I change them?

Comment: I do not see how `Ctrl+/` and Emmet are related here. I mean -- Emmet in WebStorm is implemented differently (own implementation) .. so Emmet's native shortcuts do not work here. Better say what exactly you want to be done -- maybe there is another (standard) way.

Comment: You are correct. _WebStorm_ had set the comment with block comment action to **Ctrl + Shift + /**, which is different from the standard implementation in _Emmet_. I figured I would have to change the bindings in a configuration file, but it was sufficient to change it under `Settings > Keymap > Code > Comment with Block Comment`, providing me with the functionality that I was after.